# How to animate a button change in UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am calling the `-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` method in my code to swap between two buttons on the RHS of my navigation bar.

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {  
  [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];  

  // Toggle ‘+’ and ‘Add To Order’ button.    

  if( editing ) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addItemButton;  
  }  
  else {           
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addToOrderButton;  
  } 
}
```

Where `self.addItemButton` and `self.addToOrderButton` are ivars containing predefined UIBarButtonItems, setup in `awakefromNib`.

The button in `self.addToOrderButton` is significantly wider then the one in `self.addItemButton`, so I’d like their to be a subtle animation between the two widths when the change in editing state is triggered (by tapping a standard `editButtonItem` on the LHS of the navigation.

If I surround the whole `if:else` with `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];` and `[UIView commitAnimations];` the button change does animate, but with their positions—flying into place individually from the top left—rather than in place and just animating their widths.

How I animate the navigation bar elements so that each individual one (the RHS button, the title) animate in more appropriate, restrained ways?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> ```
> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addToOrderButton;
> ```

There are specific methods you can use to animate the right and left bar button items:

```
 [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: self.addToOrderButton animated:YES];
```

...which will animate it for you. If you need everything to animate (including the title) you can also use the `setItems:animated:` method of your navigation bar (pass it in an array of the navigation items you'd like to display)

Comment: I’ve accepted the answer, as that does exactly what you describe and works okay. Many thanks. As an aside, is there a method to tweak the actual animation that's occurring? As presented here, that does a cross-fade—which is fine—but a combination of cross-fade for the text and animated move of the button LHS for the ‘frame’ would be even better.

Comment: There's no direct method in the SDK, no. You could probably implement something yourself, but it would be non-trivial (something like overriding the method with a category and replacing it with your own transition).

Comment: Sounds like something that I would need to study the docs on; thanks for getting me on the right track though.

Comment: also if you don't know you can use:
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];

this can be used in combination with:
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];

Comment: For a custom animation wouldn't it be the easiest to just replace the navigation bar with a custom view?

Comment: Before you try to use `setItems:animated:`, be aware that it cannot be used on the `navigationController`'s `navigationBar`. You'll get slapped with the following exception: `Cannot call setItems:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.`

Comment: update your method to swift 5

`var rightBarbuttonItemsArray: [UIBarButtonItem] = []

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(rightBarbuttonItemsArray, animated: true)`