# Show/Hide barButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to show/hide a `UIBarButtonItem`. I added a `barButton` to the right side in the `storyboard`. Then in `viewDidLoad`, I made the `rightBarButtonItem` to `nil`. Later on, I set it to the `button` I added in the `storyboard`. Here's my code:

```
// Right barButtonItem added in storybord:
@IBOutlet weak var deleteBarButton: UIBarButtonItem! 

// viewDidLoad
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

// Later on...
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.deleteBarButton
```

When I set `self.deleteBarButton` to the `rightBarButtonItem`, nothing happens. It doesn't show it. What am I doing wrong, and what's the correct/most efficient way to show/hide a `barButtonItem`?

**Update**

I tried the following:

```
self.deleteBarButton.hidden = true
```

But I get the following error:

> `UIBarButtonItem` does not have a member named 'hidden'

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I have added a way to make the barbuttonitem clear (and thus not visible to the user)

Comment: Check out "Update 2" in my answer

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just got the answer! All you have to do is create a `strong IBOutlet`, then you can do the following:

```
// viewDidLoad
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

// Later on...
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.deleteBarButton
```

Comment: While this works there is a better and supported way to do this which supports animation http://stackoverflow.com/a/5006889/1166266

Comment: I tried assigning `rightBarButtonItem` to `nil` in Objective C it doesn't work

Comment: Swift 3.1 | Works great |   // viewDidLoad     self.rightBarButtonAlert.isEnabled = false   self.rightBarButtonAlert.tintColor = .clear

Comment: @Jessica,,,,,
thanks...

Comment: must use a strong IBOutlet, not a weak one

Comment: getting Nil cannot be assigned to type 'UIBarButtonItem'

Comment: Suppose if I have two bar button item in the right side, and I need to hide only one, how can I do that?

Answer (score 29):

**Update 2**

You could just set the button's text to nothing:

```
self.deleteBarButton.title = "";
```

**Update 1**

I would use the `enabled` property to illuminate the button as follows (although it does not completely make the button invisible, it allows the user to know it will not perform an action).

This can act as a variable to let you know that the button is hidden in your case:

Illuminated: (place in ViewDidLoad)

```
self.deleteBarButton.enabled = true;
```

Darkened: (place later on)

```
self.deleteBarButton.enabled = false;
```

Then I would add the following to make it completely disappear:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have to completely hide it

Answer (score 7):

Try to create your barButton manually in viewDidLoad and then show/hide your button.

Code:

```
var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("target_function"))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}

func someFunction() {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    // or
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

Comment: For those using a UINavigationBar by itself (not the controller version), you can add a weak IBOutlet reference and then set the right/left bar button items like so (notice the topItem? - I am using navigationBar as my reference name), where barButton is either an IBOutlet reference, or as @mks defined: navigationBar.topItem?.setLeftBarButton(barButton, animated: true)