# Remove Navigation Bar back button text App-Wide in iOS 15 / XCode 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

So my app has been doing the following piece of code on the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method on the AppDelegate to hide the back button text on navigation bar:

```
let itemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    itemAppearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -200, vertical: 0), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

To my surprise, among other things which I already solved (such as [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/684454)), the above code no longer works on iOS 15 & XCode 13.

Ive been searching alternatives such as:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Which seem to be working just fine, however this works on a specific ViewController and Id like this to work App-Wide, having to run this code on every VC is annoying.

I tried to run the above code on the same app delegate method, but sadly I dont have access to navigationItem on AppDelegate.

Any tip is welcomed, thanks!

PD: Ideally this would need to support all the way back to iOS 13.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/Hide barButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553197/show-hide-barbuttonitem)

Comment: Hmm I dont think it does, if Im not mistaken that deals with the actual UIBarButtonItem icon, not the text attached to it. Plus the answers all point to a per-VC solution, I need to disable the back button text app-wide.